# Cohomology theory "from" Grothendieck's six operations?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

How, precisely, (as suggested by grothendieck) cohomology theory naturally follows from the Grothendieck's six operations associated to the category derived from the topos?

I would like some references.

Comment: The most general reference I know of is this: http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2110, but I hope someone will show up and give a more beginner-friendly one.

Comment: I don't think I can parse your question, but cohomology is (derived) pushing forward to a point- which is one of the 6 operations.

Comment: @DylanWilson I am interpreting the question by asking to reduce the usual properties of a cohomology theory (e.g. duality, projection formula, cycle class map...) to the formalism of six operations rather than just defining the cohomology theory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have the usual 6 operations we have the following recipes for co/homologies of $f \colon X \to Y$ with coefficients $\mathcal{F}$ over $X$, $\mathcal{G}$ over $Y$ and $\mathcal{O}$ denoting the monoidal unit.

Cohomology:........................................... $\mathrm{Hom}_X(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$

Homology:.............................................. $\mathrm{Hom}_X(\mathcal{O}_X,f^!\mathcal{G})$

Cohomology with compact support:....... $\mathrm{Hom}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y,f_!\mathcal{F})$

Borel-Moore homology:......................... $\mathrm{Hom}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y,f_!f^!\mathcal{G})$

The defining relations between the 6 functors yield the usual dualities and comparison maps between the four theories. Notice that when f is proper $f_! = f_*$ and the latter pair becomes the first.

Comment: I am confused by the role of O here. Shouldn't the first two rows be just f_*F and f_*f^! G ? While the last become f_!F and f_! f^! G?

Comment: @Mattias Volkov If $Y$ is affine, then your definitions agree with mine (after taking the associated sheaf). In the general case you give a sheafified version of co/homology while my definitions provide abelian groups, in fact modules over $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ for the first two and over $\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ for the remaining ones.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see Y playing any role in your definition. For example, when f is the identity, don't your definitions of "cohomology with compact support" and "cohomology" with coefficients in F coincide? That just seems wrong to me. That's why I thought you should replace the definition with my comment above, which gives the correct answer when Y is a point. [also, in your comment I think you want Y a point (or maybe contractible) because in general affine varieties have non-trivial cohomology.]

Comment: The philosophy behind these definitions is that of relative objects. They express invariants "along the fibers". For an absolute cohomology, use a contractible base or the absolute base. The 6 operations formalism is geared towards a relative version of co/homology in the spirit of Grothendieck.

Comment: It's missing a $f_{*}$ in the first one if you want something relative.

Comment: Maybe I'm conflating some things, but, for a point at least, Borel-Moore is $H^{-i} (f_{*} \omega_X)$ and the ordinary homology is $H^{-i} (f_{!} \omega_X)$. So I think the correct would be ${f_{*}f^{!}}$ and $f_{!}f^{!}$ for the BM homology and homology, respectively.

Comment: @user40276 There is no need of $f_*$ because I wrote *global* Ext's. If you want a sheafified version then you have to throw some $f_*$ into the formulas. Notice the subindices in the Ext modules.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your notation, but as I understand $H^0 (Hom_X (\mathscr{O}_X, \mathscr{F})) = \Gamma (X, \mathscr{F})$ if your $Hom_X$ is in the derived category. If your $Hom_X$ is just the abelian group, then, again, $Hom_X (\mathscr{O}_X, \mathscr{F}) = \Gamma (X, \mathscr{F})$. So the $Y$ is not being taking into account at all.

Comment: @user40276 I was implicitly meaning that everything corresponds to the derived category setting. The cohomologies of $R Hom^{\bullet}_X (\mathscr{O}_X, \mathscr{F})$ are the $H^i (X, \mathscr{F})$ which turn out to be $\Gamma (Y, \mathscr{O}_Y)$-modules. Ditto for the rest of formulas. I omitted the notation of derived Hom complex for brevity